# Mapping over array of objects - unable to get values into dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The title pretty much explains my issue. I mocked up some data I need to display in a dropdown, the dropdown component is from [SUIR](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/)

```
mock.onGet("/slotIds").reply(200, {
  data: {
    slotIds: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
  }
});
```

I'm updating state with the fetch of the data

```
  const { data } = await axios.get("/slotIds");
  console.log("Slot IDs --> ", data);
  const slotIds = data.data;
  this.setState({ slotIds: slotIds });
  console.log(this.state.slotIds);
  //the above log outputs [Object, Object, Object] so slotIds is in fact an array
```

Then I'm mapping over that values to render the `id` in a dropdown

```
        options={slotIds.map(id => {
          return {
            key: id.id,
            text: id.id,
            value: id.id
          };
        })}
```

Can't quite get it to work, am I mapping the values incorrectly or returning the wrong values?

I have a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/logincomponent-fy12t) that reproduces the issue. You will need to click on the the `Login` button at the top of the splash page. Select the `Slot Sec Officer` radio button, look at the console it will show the successful api call and how the `slotIds` state is updated. I have commented out the `.map` function because it is causing the component not rendering when `Slot Sec Officer` option is chosen.

The entire `Login` code is inside `/components/Login.js`. The class `SlotSecIdInputs` contains the api call and the actual `<Dropdown>` component that has the map function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of mistakes in a `SlotSecIdInputs`:

1. You haven't defined your state `slotIds` in a constructor
2. The default state should be defined as an array, cuz you mapping over fetched items which later stored as an array
3. You should control the fetch loading.

Initially when the component is just rendered you don't have `slotIds` state, so you cant map over it and you get an error. After you fetched `slotIds` you should make sure it's not empty and after it do mapping over it.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed your first/second point. Lots of similar variable names and I just missed it. What do you mean by control the fetch loading?

Comment: The `slotId` dropdown when selected is updating the value to formik state but it's not reflected in the actual dropdown itself